# python3: exceptions to a rule: issue with my logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

In the parent directory O, I have a series of directories Aa, where a varies from 0-1. In each of these I have a series of  directories Bb, where b varies from 0-1. In each of these there are the input/output files AaBbCc.dat and AaBbCc.out for some calculations [c also varies from 0-1]. However, due to a limit on the amount of resources I can use some of these calculations failed to complete (or even run).

I have created a file 'walltime.txt' which lists the output files [AaBbCc.out] that have closed prior to the calculation finishing. It is from here that the variables a, b and c take there values.

I am trying to write a program which, overall takes the names of the files that haven't completed, works out the names of those that haven't run and writes all of these into a batch file.

i.e.
The filename A0.8B0.6C0.9.out appears in 'walltime.txt'.
As such: inp = A0.8B0.6C0.9.dat; outp = A0.8B0.6C0.9.out; a = 0.8; b = 0.6 and c = 0.9
The list GULP is then formed: GULP = ['gulp < ' + inp + ' > ' + outp]

**N.B. As I will want to add to this, I am assuming it cannot just be a variable, but a one item list.**

In order to work out if there are any files in the directory that haven't run, I need to do the following [which was the original post]:

*When `c` does not equal `1.00`, extend the list `GULP` to include `gulp < ' + AaBbCc.dat + ' > ' + AaBbCc.out`. This must always happen, except when `a == 0.3 and b == 0.2` and when `a == 0.8 and c == 0.6`*.

Does this actually make any logical sense?

If so, how do I go about implementing such a piece of code in python 3: I know I am going to need an if loop for the first bit, but am unsure as to how to build in the exception.

I found literature on 'except', but this seemed to be more designed for a 'trial and improvement' methodology, and about catching errors that occur in programs. Would it still be possible for me to implement the except function?

Comment: What would the loop be over?  Where are you getting values for a, b & c?  What do you mean by "extending the list to include a b c.Letter (and example would be helpful)?

Comment: @ScottHunter post edited in order to give context

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
for each set of (a b c) values:
    if ( c != cantalope ):
        if ( a==apple and b==banana ) or ( a==avacado and c==cherry ):
            continue
        add (a b c.Letter) to shopping
```